# Get Exchange mails from Grails app

Tags: email, grails, exchange-server

I want to grab (from my grails app) every email that is sent to a specific email address, parse it, get some data and write that data in my database. Its Exchange Server mail.

I guess I could somehow start Outlook service for a given email account and check the inbox folder in, for example every 10 sec, and if there are new mails - get them.

Is this approach OK? Or should I use some service? Can someone point me in the right direction? What are my options? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your exchange server supports IMAP then you can use the normal JavaMail mechanisms to connect to it and either poll for new mail or (better) get the server to push new messages to your app as follows (error handling omitted, and there are many possible error conditions unfortunately...):

```
boolean finished = false

void setup() {
  Properties props = new Properties()
  props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps")
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
  Store store = session.getStore("imaps")
  store.connect("mailserver.example.com", "username", "password")
  Folder inFolder = currentMailStore.getFolder("INBOX")
  inFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
  inFolder.addMessageCountListener(this)
  while(!finished) {
    inFolder.idle()
    sleep(10000)
  }
}

public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
  for(Message m in e.messages) {
    //...
  }
}
```

The idea of `idle` is that the server will call your `messagesAdded` method (from the `MessageCountListener` interface) whenever a new message arrives.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. I've implemented it as a Grails service. Should I start it as a quartz job or what? Will messageAdded method automatically start because of addMessageCountListener?

Comment: The call to `inFolder.idle` will block the thread in which it is called. When a message arrives during an idle, your `messagesAdded` will be called in a different thread. If you do anything within that method that touches the folder the idle call will return, which is why you need to sleep for a few seconds (to let `messagesAdded` do its thing) and then call idle again to wait for the next message.

Comment: I use a one shot quartz job to get the whole process going to start with.